# muteHttpExceptions = true throws authentication failure

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, oauth-2.0

Using the [Google Apps Email Settings API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/) a delegate is deleted with the script below. If an error occurs, for example trying to delete delegates that do not exist, the following message is returned:

> Exception: Request failed for  returned code 400. Truncated server
>   response: <xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
>    <AppsForYourDomainErrors>    <error errorCode="1303"
>   invalidInput="XXXX@XXXX.com" reason="E... (use muteHttpExceptions
>   option to examine full response)

However when using `muteHttpExceptions = true` the authentication fails:

> Exception: Failed to authenticate for service: google

This forces me to use a try / catch structure instead of examining the `HTTPResponse` object. I would like to know why this is happening and how to solve it.

The test function:

```
   function test() {
      var consumerKey = 'XXXX';
      var consumerSecret = 'XXXX';
      var domain = 'XXXX.com';
      var userName = 'XXXX'
      var delegateName = 'XXXX@XXXX.com'
      var serviceName = 'google';
      var scope = 'https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/emailsettings/2.0/';


      var oAuthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService(serviceName);
      oAuthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl('https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope=' + scope);
      oAuthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl('https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken');
      oAuthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl('https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken');
      oAuthConfig.setConsumerKey(consumerKey);
      oAuthConfig.setConsumerSecret(consumerSecret);

      var fetchParameters = {};
      fetchParameters.oAuthServiceName = serviceName;
      fetchParameters.oAuthUseToken = 'always';
      fetchParameters.method = 'DELETE';
      fetchParameters.muteHttpExceptions = false;

      try {
        var url = 'https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/emailsettings/2.0/'+ domain + '/' + userName + '/delegation/' + delegateName;
        var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, fetchParameters);
      } catch (e) {
        Logger.log(e);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been posted to the Google Apps Script issue tracker as [ticket 3478](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3478) and [acknowledged as a bug](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3478#c3). The ticket remains open but [the following workaround has been proposed](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3478#c6):

> 1. Revoking access in your Google Account's Security settings to both www.google.com AND the source of Apps Script (spreadsheet etc).
> 2. Change the oAuthServiceName parameter to something else.
> 3. Re-running the script