# Google Script 403 Error on 2/7 days a week

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm new to this forum, was wondering if someone would be able to help me out.

I use a Google Script to track the number of Instagram followers on my company's Instagram account in a Google Sheet.

The script ran nicely for about six weeks, but during the last 2 weeks, on two successive days per week I get an error e-mail that reads:

> Request failed for https://www.instagram.com/hy.am_studios/?__a=1
>   returned code 403. Truncated server response: <html... (use
>   muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response). (line 14, file
>   "Code")

The code of the script is as follows:

```
// the name of the sheet within your document
var sheetName = "Marketing // Instagram Follower Tracker";
// the name of the Instagram account you want the follower count for
var instagramAccountName = "hy.am_studios";

function insertFollowerCount() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(this.sheetName);
  sheet.appendRow([Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "dd/MM/yyyy"), getInstagramFollowerCount(this.instagramAccountName)]);  
 };

function getInstagramFollowerCount(username) {
  var url = "https://www.instagram.com/" + username + "/?__a=1";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  return JSON.parse(response).user.followed_by.count;
}
```

Can anyone make any sense of this? What really irritates me is that the script runs on five days a week but always generates this error on two days a week.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Best wishes,

David

Answer (score 0):

Referred with this [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20238787/mutehttpexceptions-true-throws-authentication-failure). The suggested [workaround](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3478) is by revoking access in your Google Account's Security settings to both www.google.com and the source of Apps Script (spreadsheet etc). Then change the `oAuthServiceName` parameter to something else and rerun the script.

> You may also check this [thread](http://tutel.me/c/programming/questions/24393995/creating+a+group+with+admin+sdk+directory+api+in+google+apps+script++error+403):
>
> 1. Went to Resources - Advanced Google Services...
> 2. Clicked the link for the Google Developers Console
> 3. Clicked on the Credentials section in the sidebar
> 4. Clicked Create New Key under Public API access
> 5. Clicked Browser Key
> 6. Added "?key=" followed by the key that it generated to the end of the url string
>
> So the complete url string looked like this:
>
> ```
> var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups?key=XXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXX';
> ```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, will try this out!